# How can I use an user Entry to change a filename'?

Tags: python, tkinter, xlsxwriter, os.path

I'm new at learning python, so I need help with this because I don't know people that can help me. I'm trying to make a program in which the user is able to change a filename from excel depending on what they have written on an `Fname = Entry()` from tkinter.

I've tried to save the data from the Entry named as `Fname` by using `a = Fname.get()` and then `os.rename(Test.xlsx, a + " .xlsx")` to get the data stored. But I always get an error:

```
    a = Fname.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Another thing I tried was using 'Fname' insted of just 'a', but i get this error:

```
    os.rename("Test.xlsx", Fname + " .xlsx")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I also tried to directly change 'workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(Fnam + " .xlsx")', but the error still came up

PD: I don't get any trouble with creating the '.xlsx' file

The code I'm using is the next one:

```
     import xlsxwriter
     import os.path
     from tkinter import *

     def run():
         a = Fname.get()
         os.rename("Test.xlsx", Fname + " .xlsx")

     screen = Tk()

     B1 = Button(text = "Name", command = run).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

     Fname = Entry().grid(row = 1, column = 1)

     BE = Button(text = "Exit").grid(row = 3, column = 3)

     workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Test.xlsx")
     worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
     worksheet.write("A1", "Question")
     worksheet.write("B1", "Answer")
     workbook.close()

     screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are assigning `Fname` to the value after gridding which is `None` you need to split the line

```
Fname = Entry().grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

into

```
Fname = Entry()
Fname.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

You will run into similar problems if you later try to refer to `B1` or `BE` for the same reason.

Also you need to use a `StringVar()` to be able to call `.get()`

Your code should look something like this I'd imagine

```
import xlsxwriter
import os.path
from tkinter import *

def run():
    a = user_input.get()
    os.rename("Test.xlsx", a + ".xlsx")

screen = Tk()

B1 = Button(text="Name", command=run)
B1.grid(row=2, column=2)

user_input = StringVar()
Fname = Entry(textvariable=user_input)
Fname.grid(row=1, column=1)

BE = Button(text="Exit")
BE.grid(row=3, column=3)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write("A1", "Question")
worksheet.write("B1", "Answer")
workbook.close()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the error message still came up.

Comment: @PedroElizaldeAcevedo I imagine it is a different error, but you also need to change `os.rename("Test.xlsx", Fname + " .xlsx")` to `os.rename("Test.xlsx", a + ".xlsx")`